CiviCalendar Dashlet not showing
I am using CiviCRM on Wordpress installed on Arch Linux. I am currently using version 5.70.2 of CiviCRM. I am trying to use the CiviCalender extension and the dashlet does not show.

the same problem, civicrm on wordpress, on cpanel host

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
